# How can i fix the problem and avoid writing a double & in the array?

Tags: arrays, columns

I've been reading the documentation and some other previous questions but I don't find what I am doing bad in my definition of the `newcolumntype` `A` in order not to write a double `&` when writing the columns in the array.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[main=spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{ejercicio}{Ejercicio}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\ado~}r}

\newcounter{ado}[ejercicio]
\newcommand*{\ado}
 {\stepcounter{ado} \makebox[2em][r]{\alph{ado}})~}

\begin{document}

\begin{ejercicio} Un ejercicio. %this one has the desired aspect
\[
\begin{array}{rlrlrl}
\ado & 2^1= & \ado & 2^2= & \ado & 2^3= 
\end{array}
\]
\end{ejercicio}

\begin{ejercicio} Otro ejercicio. %the one to be fixed
\[
\begin{array}{AlAlAl}
2^1= && 2^2= && 2^3=
\end{array}
\]
\end{ejercicio}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look on your definition of the columntype `A`:

```
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\ado~}r}
```

The effect is: Put a right-aligned column (`r`) and at the user-defined command `\ado` to the beginning of it (`>{\ado}`). Which means that you create a column with text that you can insert into this cell.

In the definition of your array, you use `AlAlAl` meaning: You have first a right-aligned column with the extra text added to it, then a left-aligned column without extra text, and these two three times. But what you actually want to do is to have only *one* column and extra text.

So there are two possible solutions:

- Remove the `r` from the definition of `A`, and then use `AlAlAl`.
- Keep this definition of `A`, but use `AAA` only.

This example shows both ways, but defines the second way as `B`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[main=spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{ejercicio}{Ejercicio}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\ado~}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\ado~}r}

\newcounter{ado}[ejercicio]
\newcommand*{\ado}{\stepcounter{ado}\makebox[2em][r]{\alph{ado}})~}

\begin{document}

\begin{ejercicio} Un ejercicio.
\[
\begin{array}{rlrlrl}
\ado & 2^1= & \ado & 2^2= & \ado & 2^3= 
\end{array}
\]
\end{ejercicio}

\begin{ejercicio} Otro ejercicio.
\[
\begin{array}{AlAlAl}
2^1= & 2^2= & 2^3=
\end{array}
\]
\end{ejercicio}

\begin{ejercicio} Tertio ejercicio.
\[
\begin{array}{BBB}
2^1= & 2^2= & 2^3=
\end{array}
\]
\end{ejercicio}

\end{document}
```

[image]